# ffmpeg timecode and -r

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, timecode

Following up on this question: [ffmpeg drawtext timecode source framerate](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/ffmpeg-drawtext-timecode-source-framerate/24009)

I want to change the frame rate of a file, scale it down and burn the timecode in one operation.

`ffmpeg -i in.mpg -r 24 -vf "scale=-2:360, drawtext=timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=24:" out.mpg`

When I do this, the timecode is relative to the source frame rate, not the output. So if my input FPS is 59.94, I get this timecode sequence:

```
00:00:00:02
00:00:00:04
00:00:00:07
00:00:00:09
```

How can I tell `drawtext` to use destination frame numbers instead of source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filter to reduce the framerate beforehand

```
ffmpeg -i in.mpg -vf "fps=24,scale=-2:360,drawtext=timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=24" out.mpg
```

Comment: Thank you @Gyan! Your answers are fast and accurate.

So now I have a followup question: if I were only changing the frame rate, would there be any difference between `-r 24` and `vf fps=24`?

Comment: There was a difference in frame selection logic for the first frame but I believe it was fixed recently.